# Exchanging subpartitioned partitions in Oracle 11g2

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning

I have two tables, with identical partitioning and sub-partitioning, populated with some dummy data:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TBL_1(col_1 number, col_2 number, col_3 number, col_4 number ,col_5 VARCHAR2(100))
  PARTITION BY RANGE (col_1, col_2, col_3)
  SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (col_4)
(
  PARTITION PDUMMY
    VALUES LESS THAN (-1, -1, -1)
    ( SUBPARTITION SPDUMMY VALUES LESS THAN (-1)),
  PARTITION P_1_1_1
    VALUES LESS THAN (1, 1, 1)
    ( SUBPARTITION SP_1_1_1_1000 VALUES LESS THAN (1000),
      SUBPARTITION SP_1_1_1_2000 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
      SUBPARTITION SP_1_1_1_3000 VALUES LESS THAN (3000)),
  PARTITION P_2_2_2
    VALUES LESS THAN (2, 2, 2)
    ( SUBPARTITION SP_2_2_2_1000 VALUES LESS THAN (1000),
      SUBPARTITION SP_2_2_2_2000 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
      SUBPARTITION SP_2_2_2_3000 VALUES LESS THAN (3000)));

CREATE TABLE TEST_TBL_2(col_1 number, col_2 number, col_3 number, col_4 number ,col_5 VARCHAR2(100))
  PARTITION BY RANGE (col_1, col_2, col_3)
  SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (col_4)
(
  PARTITION PDUMMY
    VALUES LESS THAN (-1, -1, -1)
    ( SUBPARTITION SPDUMMY VALUES LESS THAN (-1)),
  PARTITION P_1_1_1
    VALUES LESS THAN (1, 1, 1)
    ( SUBPARTITION SP_1_1_1_1000 VALUES LESS THAN (1000),
      SUBPARTITION SP_1_1_1_2000 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
      SUBPARTITION SP_1_1_1_3000 VALUES LESS THAN (3000)),
  PARTITION P_2_2_2
    VALUES LESS THAN (2, 2, 2)
    ( SUBPARTITION SP_2_2_2_1000 VALUES LESS THAN (1000),
      SUBPARTITION SP_2_2_2_2000 VALUES LESS THAN (2000),
      SUBPARTITION SP_2_2_2_3000 VALUES LESS THAN (3000)));


INSERT INTO TEST_TBL_1(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) values (1,1,0,500,  'TABLE 1: Partition P_1_1_1 subpartition SP_1_1_1_1000');
INSERT INTO TEST_TBL_1(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) values (1,1,0,1300, 'TABLE 1: Partition P_1_1_1 subpartition SP_1_1_1_2000');
INSERT INTO TEST_TBL_1(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) values (1,1,0,2700, 'TABLE 1: Partition P_1_1_1 subpartition SP_1_1_1_3000');
INSERT INTO TEST_TBL_1(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) values (1,1,0,2990, 'TABLE 1: Partition P_1_1_1 subpartition SP_1_1_1_3000');


INSERT INTO TEST_TBL_2(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) values (1,1,0,700,  'TABLE 2: Partition P_1_1_1 subpartition SP_1_1_1_1000');
INSERT INTO TEST_TBL_2(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) values (1,1,0,1500, 'TABLE 2: Partition P_1_1_1 subpartition SP_1_1_1_2000');
INSERT INTO TEST_TBL_2(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) values (1,1,0,2222, 'TABLE 2: Partition P_1_1_1 subpartition SP_1_1_1_3000');
INSERT INTO TEST_TBL_2(col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5) values (1,1,0,2323, 'TABLE 2: Partition P_1_1_1 subpartition SP_1_1_1_3000');
```

My goal is to exchange partitions from table 1 with corresponding partitions from table 2, including all subpartitions data. But if I use exchange partition syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE test_tbl_1
EXCHANGE PARTITION P_1_1_1
WITH TABLE test_tbl_2 ;
```

I would end up with an error:

```
ORA-14293: Number of partitioning columns does not match number of subpartitioning columns
```

Is there a way to exchange partitions between those tables in one statement? If no, could you please guide me through the most efficient way to do this step by step?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are doing a partition exchange, you are exchanging either:

1. a partitioned table with a non partitioned table
   or
2. a sub-partitioned table with a partitioned table.

So you would need to use two steps in your case. You would have a dummy table that was partitioned. Then you would

Exchange table_1 partition_1 with dummy
Exchange table_2 partition_1 with dummy

You would repeat that for all the required partitions.